# Visual signs of a quality power supply

Tags: power-supply

What are some visual indicators of a quality power supply?
I'm currently outside of US, and all the brands are ones that I have never heard of... so no user reviews.

How can I tell that I am buying a quality supply vs buying a cheap power supply for high price?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Outside the US, e.g. in the UK, people still buy the same makes.. of all the components.  I know of no maker of british power supplies for computers.  or british hard drives.. There is one company called Draytek a british make of routers.. but really most makes are american.  You go to a computer store or ebay.. maybe you're looking in the wrong stores.  Infact, most people buying power supplies probably buy them online, unless it's needed immediately.

Comment: I'm over in Asian, and unfortunately, there's a ton of them that don't have a big brandname.  Or perhaps I don't recognize the brand in Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not visual.. but I look at the weight specs.  Generally a good power supply has beefy components and weigh more.  Certainly one that has plug-in cables is a sign of a better supply (versus just total cable trunk exiting PS)